# Typescript libraries are not available when running mocha tests

Tags: typescript

I created some tests that uses `lib.dom.d.ts` types such as Crypto. However, when running the tests, it throws a ReferenceError.

`ReferenceError: Crypto is not defined`

I understand that the tests are run on node so these types are not available. However the javascript I am testing is something to be loaded on browser and it used these types from `lib.dom.d.ts`. If I want to test it, I need those types available.

This is specified on my tsconfig.json under compilerOptions

`"lib": ["es2017", "dom"]`

Comment: Your problem is not with type declarations, but with the `Crypto` implementation actually being available at runtime.  It sounds like you need either a polyfill or an alternate browser-based testing environment.

Comment: Yeah, an alternative is to polyfill them. 
What I am doing however on tests is to mock all these browser-based types so there is no need to polyfill. The problem however is this referenced error.

Comment: If you are correctly mocking `Crypto`, then you shouldn't get an error when you try to use it.  Or does the error occur while you are trying to install the mocking because the `Crypto` object needs to already exist?  In that case, you could just try setting `Crypto = {}`.

Comment: Yes, it fails because Crypto types does not exists..It did not work as it is the type I need.

Comment: I am using this to mock Crypto.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito/v/0.1.10
`const mockCrypto = mock(Crypto);`

Comment: Please add example code sufficient to reproduce the problem to the question.